# Generic USB IR receiver/transmitter with Linux machine

Tags: usb, infrared

I bought a generic USB IR receiver/emitter from amazon: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01N1F8U58/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I didn't find any specific drivers for these kind of USB devices (as they're made to connect directly to USB IR slots on terminals and TVs), but I thought they could be controllable from a lower-level, like the home-made GPIO-to-IR LED transmitters on a RPI3.

When connected, it does not show in dmesg, lsusb or syslog. It is not detected on a Windows PC either.

Then, is it possible to somehow connect to these devices to send IR commands ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible, as this is not what you thought it is. Read the Q&A and reviews at the amazon item page you sent.

It is simple IR repeater to extend the range, and USB is there only for power (you could get it with other endings like 3.5mm audio jack for providing it with required 5V)

as mentioned on the product page:

> Question: Can this usb adapter send and receive an ir signal, eg. via a raspberry pi?
>
> Answer: Usb is for power. As far as I know this device
> only extends an existing ir receiver. By RAHK on January 2, 2018
>
> The USB adapter on this Ir receiver/ sender is a convient way to power the
> electronics 5vdc. It is not for receiving or sending serial data
> protocols By Mike on January 3, 2018

So you would use it if you had problems with range from your IR trasmiter (like remote control) to your IR receiver (like set top box, TV, Air conditioner...).